# mod rewrite problems, cannot access an index file in a folder

Tags: .htaccess

I have removed .php extension from all files. However now when I try to access my admin folder I get this error:

The requested URL /admin/.php was not found on this server.

This is probably because the server is trying to give me admin.php file instead of /admin/index.php

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: There is no way to fix this if you don't tell us -exactly_ what your setup is and what you have configured. Or do you want us to _guess_ all that?

Comment: dont remove .php extension from files, use htaccess to hide php extension from all files when open on browser.

Comment: @user3527939: You need to show your existing rewrite rules in your question.